# Building mysql production rpms (stripped mysqld and mysqld-debug)

Tags: mysql, rpmbuild

I am trying to build mysql rpm, I downloaded the src rpm from mysql ([mysl-5.6.26-1.el6.src.rpm](http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/MySQL-5.6/MySQL-5.6.26-1.el6.src.rpm)) and followed these steps

```
1. rpm -i MySQL-5.6.26-1.el6.src.rpm
2. cd ~/rpmbuild
3. rpmbuild -v -bb SPECS/mysql.spec
```

This builds mysql-server-*.rpm, but the binaries and libraries inside the rpm are not stripped. Currently the `mysqld` and `mysqld-debug` combined together are more than `100M`.

How do I build an rpm with stripped binaries?

Current rpm size

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 XXXX XXXXXXX 52M Jul 31 17:43 /home/XXXX/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/MySQL-server-5.6.19-1.linux_glibc.x86_64.rpm
```